# calling another activity function inside an activity via handler doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-handler

I want to start a `CountDownTimer` from another activity. I use handlers to do that, but it doesn't work. Which part am I doing wrong?  This is my code:

`activity1.java` :

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {
public static Handler mHandler; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
initHandler();
mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class));
}

private void initHandler(){
mHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.arg1) {
        case 1:
            mCountDownTimer.start();
            break;
        }
    }
};
}

private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    Toast.makeText(Activity1.this, "Count is: "+ millisUntilFinished/1000,    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
};
}
```

`activity2.java` :

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Activity1.mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

}
}
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `initHandler()` method, change your condition in `switch` case from `switch (msg.arg1)` to `switch (msg.what)`

According to [Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) `sendEmptyMessage(int)` `Sends a Message containing only the what value.`